# How to assign transform translate to an element?

Tags: javascript, transform

I am trying to assign a transform translate value to an element. I use Webpack  and it shows error at `functions.js:104`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined"

my code:

```
const move = -1 * (moveInPercent);
console.log(move); // this output the required value
innerWrapper.style.transform = `translateY( ${move}% )`;
```

What I want to reach is

```
transform: translate(10px); // dynamically added value when scrolling.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means that `innerWrapper` isn't an HTML element

Comment: As Cristian said, you probably have wrong selector for innerWrapper..

Comment: Yes, it was a wrong selector. Thank you